# Python Try-Except: How to variabilize Logging.info?

Tags: python, variables, logging, error-logging, try-except

This would be the funniest thing you see all day. But here it is. How do I turn my printed-out exception message into a variable, so I can globalize and update them into my database?

Here is the analogy:

```
try:

except Exception as e:
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
try:

except Exception as e:
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        loginerror = logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        print str(loginerror)
```

So,I basically get None, because clearly it hasn't been variablized:

```
None
```

If needed, here's what my exception message prints out:

```
2018-08-10 09:38:00,009 - root - ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\jobtech-crawlers\crawler_parttimejobs.py", line 122, in dump_parttimejobs
    response = requests_retry_session().get(url=linkWqery)
NameError: global name 'linkWqery' is not defined
```

Comment: I'll be on standby if you need more information! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you need to get exception info in a variable? Is that correct, while still be able to log this? why not something like `globalVar = sys.exc_info()` inside the `try: except:` block and simply using `logging.exception` ? or saving `traceback.format_exc()` to a variable and passing that variable to `logging.error` as you are doing?

Comment: Yesss! Thanks. Yeah that was what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the logging.error, it returns a string of the error message.

```
try:
    print(0/0)
except Exception as e:
    x = traceback.format_exc()

print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've understood my mistake from the previous commentor. This works too! Thank you.

Comment: @HanJinn Ah sorry, didn't see their comment. Glad it worked!